# how to access vector object in another class in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am newbie to c++.I have created two classes.one class(say A) will push the struct data into vector while other class(say B) will pop out the data from the vector.

How do I pass the reference of vector from class A to B so that class B can point to same vector object to pop out data,to do some manipulation.

can anyone help me to resolve this

So far My effort  is,
A.h file:

```
struct strctOfA {
       int x;
       int y;
       int z;
    };  


class A {
public:

A();        
private:
     std::vector<strctOfA> t2;
};
```

A.cpp file:

```
         A::A() {

        strctOfA player;
        player.x=1;
        player.y=2;
        player.z=3;



        t2.push_back(player)
        B b;
        b.functionOfB(&t2); 
        }
```

B.h file

```
         class B {

        public:
             B();
             functionOfB(&t2);
        };
```

B.cpp:

```
 B::functionOfB(A &t) {
    t2.pop_front(); 
    }
```

Comment: I find a typedef to be useful:  i.e.   typdef std::vector<strctOfA>  strucOfAVec_t;  Now you can pass the vector easily:   a) use to declare t2:  strucOfAVec_t  t2; ,  and b) used to pass by ref into func (init()?)  or ctor:  (..., strucOfAVec_t& x, ... )

Answer (score 0):

Use a friend class, this is a class that has been declared as friend (with the keyword friend) in another class. It can access private and protected members of other class. It is useful to allow a particular class to access private members of the other class.
Example:

a.h

```
typedef struct strctOfA {
   int x;
   int y;
   int z;
}positions;
class A {
public:
    A();
    friend class B;
private:
    strctOfA player;
    std::vector<positions> t2;
};
```

a.cpp

```
    A::A() {
    player.x=1;
    player.y=2;
    player.z=3;
    t2.push_back(player);
}
```

b.h

```
class B {
public:
    B();
    void functionOfB(A &x);
};
```

b.cpp

```
B::B() {
}
void B::functionOfB(A &x) {
    x.t2.pop_back();
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main() {
    A instanceOfA;
    B *instanceOfB = new B();
    instanceOfB->functionOfB(instanceOfA);
    return 0;
}
```